# form for polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm wondering how to prepare working form (with simple_form) for polymorphic association. with these models:

```
class Poster < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :kind, polymorphic: true      
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posters, as: :kind
  has_many :subcategories, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subcategories

  def self.with_subcategories
    self.all.map { |category| category.subcategories }
  end  
end

class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :posters, as: :kind
end
```

i want the user to be able to create a poster, and assign it with one of existing category or subcategory. in database (posters) i have both kind_id and kind_type, but i don't know how to build a proper form. i tried something like this (just with subcategories for a test) but it is not even close to correct:

```
= simple_form_for @poster do |f|
    = f.input :description
    = f.input :title
    = f.input :kind, collection: Category.with_subcategories
    = f.submit
```

Any clues on how to do it properly?

Comment: Maybe try flattening the array in your self.with_subcategories method. Currently it looks like it would return an array of arrays of subcategories.

Comment: but still, kind_type in the database is nil, and it sucks